# Add object in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to add a object in my tableview to dynamic insert rows.

The code seems not to be working, no row is inserted.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *newString = @"test!";

    [self.greekLetters addObject:newString];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.greekLetters count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *SimpleIdentifier = @"SimpleIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = ([[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:(SimpleIdentifier)]);
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.greekLetters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Laatste datum";

    return cell;
}
```

The object isn't adding to the textlabel text and it hasn't a new row. I am new to this sort of iOS, so what's wrong with the code?

I tried many things but can't get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: `self.greekLetters` Where is it initialized? Is it `nil`?

Comment: In the viewcontroller.h. @property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *greekLetters;

Comment: Where did you do `self.greekLetters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`.

Comment: Not. Added it in Viewdidload and now I get a SIGBRT error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArray0 addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170013170'

Comment: You need to initialize your mutable array as @Larme says

Comment: Changed 'copy' to 'retain' of the property and now it works, thanks guys!

Comment: Not related, but `stringWithFormat` is not needed at all.

Comment: As @vadian stated `stringWithFormat` isn't needed, you can just use a literal init

Comment: @JacobBoyd You can even directly pass `[self.greekLetters object...]`

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant ^ :)

Comment: Could this be [a duplicate of this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429960/how-can-i-insert-row-in-a-table)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please find below code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.greekLetters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *newString = @"test!";

    [self.greekLetters addObject:newString];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.greekLetters count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *SimpleIdentifier = @"SimpleIdentifier";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = ([[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:(SimpleIdentifier)]);
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.greekLetters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Laatste datum";


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code. Explain what the problem was and explain how your answer solves the issue.